# Show main hidden form from subfrom

Tags: c#, winforms

i have 2 forms
Form1 the main form
Form2 the subform
When i open form2 i want to hide form1 <- the main
And when i close form2 i want to show form1

I tried

```
Form1 mform = new Form1();
mform.Show();
```

But its open new form not the hidden form

Found solution

In form 2

```
Form Main;
public Form2(Form MainForm)
{
    Main = MainForm;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

in form 1

```
Form2 SubForm = new Form2(this);
SubForm.Show();
this.Hide();
```

So i can show the hidden form1 from form2 by Main.Show();

Answer (score 0):

you have to keep a reference to the Main form in the Form2 instead of creating a new From.

in your Form2 you should have a property to keep a reference to the Form1 something like the blow:

```
public Form MainForm { get; set; }
```

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: You have manually set up this property when u are about to show form2

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the reference of main form to the Form1 and keep it to access it later.

```
Form1 mform = new Form1(MainForm mform);
mform.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you open a new subform FORM2, you just have to hide the main form using `form1.Hide()` and show the new one `Form2.Show()`.

When you close the subform, you just call the `form1.Show()`.

TO implement this, u gotto have reference of main form.

Answer (score 0):

there is no need for keeping the references. Use the following code in the  child form

```
if (this.ParentForm != null)
this.ParentForm.Show();
```

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: You have not set the MainForm as Parent Form of sub form.